# Tabman resizeable navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm using Tabman (it was injected before we) in project.I want to have bar in the middle and picture above, and when I'm scrolling vc below bar, picture resizes and hides. As I understand it can be done by Tabman framework. I can do it by myself, but before in this project it was done by Tabman. But I can't figure out how.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by use other framework such as : https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader

Or just custom it yourself by change view's frame size